# Convert SQL to LINQ in MVC3 with Ninject

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I'm using MVC3 and still learning LINQ.  I'm having some trouble trying to convert a query to LINQ to Entities.  I want to return an employee object.

```
SELECT E.EmployeeID, E.FirstName, E.LastName, MAX(EO.EmployeeOperationDate) AS "Last Operation"
FROM Employees E 
INNER JOIN EmployeeStatus ES ON E.EmployeeID = ES.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN EmployeeOperations EO ON ES.EmployeeStatusID = EO.EmployeeStatusID
INNER JOIN Teams T ON T.TeamID = ES.TeamID
WHERE T.TeamName = 'MyTeam'
GROUP BY E.EmployeeID, E.FirstName, E.LastName
ORDER BY E.FirstName, E.LastName
```

What I have is a few tables, but I need to get only the newest status based on the EmployeeOpertionDate.  This seems to work fine in SQL.  I'm also using Ninject and set my query to return Ienumerable.  I played around with the group by option but it then returns IGroupable.  Any guidance on converting and returning the property object type would be appreciated.

Edit:  I started writing this out in LINQ but I'm not sure how to properly return the correct type or cast this.

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployeesByTeam(int teamID)
    {

        var q = from E in context.Employees
                join ES in context.EmployeeStatuses on E.EmployeeID equals ES.EmployeeID
                join EO in context.EmployeeOperations on ES.EmployeeStatusID equals EO.EmployeeStatusID
                join T in context.Teams on ES.TeamID equals T.TeamID
                where T.TeamName == "MyTeam"
                group E by E.EmployeeID into G
                select G;
        return q;
    }
```

Edit2:

This seems to work for me

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployeesByTeam(int teamID)
    {

        var q = from E in context.Employees
                join ES in context.EmployeeStatuses on E.EmployeeID equals ES.EmployeeID
                join EO in context.EmployeeOperations.OrderByDescending(eo => eo.EmployeeOperationDate) on ES.EmployeeStatusID equals EO.EmployeeStatusID
                join T in context.Teams on ES.TeamID equals T.TeamID
                where T.TeamID == teamID
                group E by E.EmployeeID into G
                select G.FirstOrDefault();
        return q;
    }
```

Comment: did you try using `Linqer` http://www.sqltolinq.com/, there are many others too..

Comment: Your SQL query is using left outer joins while your LINQ is using inner joins meaning that your SQL is returning rows even if there are no matching rows in the other tables. Your LINQ only returns rows if there are matching data in all tables.  Just looking at what you're doing, I suspect you should be doing inner joins???

Comment: You are correct, I should be using inner joins, I'm more concerned about proper syntax right now.  I'll correct my example above.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff, your "Edit2" helped and worked for me as well! I did it like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ListCases> GetListCases(int? customerId, int? languageId, int? userGroupId) 
{    
    var query = from cfs in this.DataContext.CaseFieldSettings
            join cfsl in this.DataContext.CaseFieldSettingLanguages on cfs.Id equals cfsl.CaseFieldSettings_Id  
            join cs in this.DataContext.CaseSettings on cfs.Name equals cs.Name
            where cfsl.Language_Id == languageId && cfs.ShowOnStartPage == 1 && cfs.Customer_Id == customerId && cs.UserGroup == userGroupId && cs.Name != null  
            group cfs by new  {  
                                    cfs.Id, cfs.Customer_Id, cfsl.CaseFieldSettings_Id, cfsl.Label, cfsl.Language_Id, cfs.ShowOnStartPage, cs.Name  
                              } into grouped  

            select new ListCases  
            {  
                Id = grouped.Key.Id, CFS_Id = grouped.Key.CaseFieldSettings_Id, Label = grouped.Key.Label, Language_Id = grouped.Key.Language_Id, Customer_Id = grouped.Key.Customer_Id, Show = grouped.Key.ShowOnStartPage, CSName = grouped.Key.Name  
            };

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly clear on how your SQL query is supposed to work, but I've tried to shape your LINQ query to match what it is doing and it also returns type `Employee`. This should set you up towards getting the exact solution you need:

```
var q = from E in context.Employees
         join ES in context.EmployeeStatuses on E.EmployeeID equals ES.EmployeeID
         join EO in context.EmployeeOperations
             .OrderByDescending (x => x.EmployeeOperationDate) 
                 on ES.EmployeeStatusID equals EO.EmployeeStatusID
         join T in context.Teams on ES.TeamID equals T.TeamID
         where T.TeamName == "MyTeam"
         group new { E.EmployeeID, E.FirstName, E.LastName, EO.EmployeeOperationDate } 
             by new {E.EmployeeID, E.FirstName, E.LastName } into G
         orderby G.Key.LastName,G.Key.FirstName
         select new Employee
         {
             EmployeeID = G.Key.EmployeeID,
             FirstName = G.Key.FirstName,
             LastName = G.Key.LastName,
             LastOperation = G.First ().EmployeeOperationDate
         };
```

Comment: Thanks Brad. I also updated above what seemed to give the results I was looking for.  I need to do some testing with it.  I appreciate the sample above, I'll look at that in more detail.

Comment: Query runs fine but it doesn't do the grouping properly.  Employees has many EmployeeStatus has one EmployeeOperation.  What I'm trying to grab is the team based on the last operation (date).  If the employee had 3 status changes all three are returned in the above.